# The return value for a method isn't being returned to the main

Tags: java, eclipse

Hi all I'm new to programming and Stackoverflow (1st post) [sorry if I didn't format correctly], this is an assignment for my first class using JAVA. I know there are tons of mistakes in this so feel free to point them out, so I can learn. I want to LEARN! I have a hard time identifying logic errors and how to fix them.

I'm going to have multiple questions about this, but first I have to get the method checkID() to return to main() to verify that the user acct information matches.

I cannot change the coding for the string a, b, and c in the checkID() method, my professor coded this intentionally.

I'm no longer getting the error messages thank you!!! But now if I enter the incorrect or correct information I'm stuck in an infinite loop. The menu() method isn't called and printed to the screen and it doesn't recall the checkID() method again.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!! Thanks in advance!!!

```
/*
 This program simulates a simple ATM machine.
 User can withdraw and deposit money by entering correct acct number and password.*/

import java.util.*;

public class ATM {

    public static Scanner kbd; 

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        String acctNum, pwd, verifyID;
        int choice, attempts=0;
        double acctBal, depositAmount, withdrawAmount;

        System.out.println( "Enter account number: ");
        acctNum=kbd.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter password: ");
        pwd=kbd.nextLine();

        verifyID=checkID(acctNum, pwd); 
        //calls checkID method and returns result to verify

        while(verifyID.equals("error") && attempts<=3) 
            //checkID returns "error" and the attempts are less than or equal to 3.
        {
            if (attempts==4) //If Maximum attempts reached display message, then exit. 
            {
                System.out.print("Maxium attemps reached.");
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
        acctBal=Double.parseDouble(verifyID); 
        //Changing the string from checkID method to double *(acct balance is returned)

        choice=menu();//Calls menu() method.

        switch (choice)
        {
        case(1)://user enters balance option.
            displayBalance(acctBal); //Call method displayBalance.
        break;
        case(2)://User enters deposit option.
            System.out.println("Enter amount to deposit: ");
            depositAmount=kbd.nextDouble();
            acctBal=deposit(acctBal,depositAmount);//call method deposit().
            System.out.printf("Your new account balance is: $%.2f"+acctBal); //Print new acctBal to screen.
        break;      
        case (3)://User enters withdraw option.
            System.out.println("Enter amout to withdraw: ");
            withdrawAmount=kbd.nextDouble();
            acctBal=withdraw(acctBal, withdrawAmount);//call method withdraw().
            System.out.printf("Your new account balance is: $%.2f"+acctBal);
        break;
        case(4)://User enters log-out
            System.out.println("You are logged out.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public static void displayBalance(double acctBal)
    {
        System.out.printf("Your current balance is : $%.2f" + acctBal);
    }

    /*The checkID method determines if acctNum is a valid account number
    and pwd is the correct password for the account.  If the account information
    is valid, the method returns the current account balance, as a string.
    If the account information is invalid, the method returns the string "error".*/

    public static String checkID(String acctNum, String pwd)
    {
        String result = "error";

        /* Strings a, b, and c contain the valid account numbers and passwords.
        For each string, the account number is listed first, followed by
        a space, followed by the password for the account, followed by a space,
        followed by the current balance.*/
        String a = "44567-5 mypassword 520.36";
        String b = "1234567-6 anotherpassword 48.20";
        String c = "4321-0 betterpassword 96.74";

        if(acctNum.equals(a.substring(0, a.indexOf(" "))) && 
                pwd.equals(a.substring(a.indexOf(" "), a.lastIndexOf(" " +1))))
        {
            result=a.substring(a.lastIndexOf(" ") +1, -1);
        }
        else if (acctNum.equals(b.substring(0, b.indexOf(" "))) && 
                pwd.equals(b.substring(b.indexOf(" "), b.lastIndexOf(" " +1))))
        {
            result=b.substring(b.lastIndexOf(" ") +1, -1);
        }
        else if (acctNum.equals(c.substring(0, c.indexOf(" "))) && 
                pwd.equals(c.substring(c.indexOf(" "), c.lastIndexOf(" " +1))))
        {
            result=c.substring(c.lastIndexOf(" ") +1, -1);
        }
        return result;

        // insert code here to determine if acctNum is a valid account number
        // and pwd is the correct password for the account.
    }

    public static double deposit(double acctBal, double depositAmount)
    {   
        return acctBal=acctBal + depositAmount;
    }
    public static double withdraw(double acctBal, double withdrawAmount)
    {
        if (acctBal<=withdrawAmount)
        {
            System.out.println("Insuffienct funds.");
            return acctBal;
        }
        else
        {
            return acctBal-withdrawAmount;
        }   
    }

    public static int menu()
    {
        int input=0; 
        while (input>=0 || input<=5) //check side
            //Checking input from user is between 1-4.
        {
            System.out.println("Main Menu\n1. Display Balance\n\n2. Deposit\n\n"
                    + "3. Withdraw\n\n4. Log Out\n\n(Please enter 1, 2, 3, or 4):");
            input=kbd.nextInt();

            if (input<=0 ||input>=5)
                //If input is not between 1-4 print error.
            {
                System.out.println("Invaid input.");
            }
            else 
            {
                return input;
            }   
        }
        return input;
    }
}
```

Comment: First you should limit your code to the relevant area of the error.  Your errror string gives you 2 very important pieces of information, the error thrown `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` and the approximate area it thinks the error originated `ATM.checkID(ATM.java:95)`. Now if you search for what the error code means you get ["Thrown by String methods to indicate that an index is either negative or greater than the size of the string"] (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.html). You are adressing space outside of your string length.

Comment: Your program has a bug. It's checking negative string indexes in CheckID(). You have an error message that tells you exactly that. Fix the bug, and your function will return to main.

Comment: Welcome to Java and StackOverflow. The most important thing to learn to use is the [Java API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/String.html). In this case I pointed you to the page about `String` where you can find the `substring` method. Look at the definition of the second parameter. Can you spot what your first mistake is?

Comment: One problem I often see new programmers do is write entire programs in one go, and then wonder why it doesn't work. A valuable lessen, that I still use, 6 years after I started programming is to: divide the overall problem into smaller problems, and then solve each of these problems individually before going on to the next problem. If a sub problem is too big, divide it further into smaller problems.

Comment: Hi @RealSkeptic thanks for the link hopefully and I can learn to use it. Is there any pointers to using it effectively?  So it should be like this ...a.substring(lastIndexOf(" ")+1) instead of like this ...a.substing(lastIndexOf(" +1")?

Comment: `lastIndexOf(" " + 1)` gives you the last index of " 1" in your string (do you understand why?), which is certainly not what you want. But that's a different issue than the one I was talking about. The answer to my question is Radiodef`s answer below.

Comment: Because it thinks that I'm looking for the last 1 in the string instead of the last space of the string and then add 1. Right?

Comment: Ask a new question about each specific problem. Edits that change question meaning are discouraged.

Comment: Thx @Basilevs will do in the future!

Answer (score 1):

```
c.substring(..., -1);
```

I know that some libraries like Python allow a negative index to mean something like "from the end in reverse" but it's not valid for Java.

In Java you'd need to do

```
result = c.substring(c.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1, c.length());
```

Or just

```
result = c.substring(c.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);
```

See also [`substring(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-) and [`substring(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-).

Answer (score 0):

use

```
acctNum=kbd.next();
```

and

```
pwd=kbd.next();
```

instead of nextLine!

Comment: I tried that, I still get the same error message. Isn't nextLine() for strings?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you refactor the `checkID` method. First, you could write three utility methods to get the balance, account number ans password respectively. Second, your accounts should probably be in an array.

```
private static Double getBalance(String str) {
    return Double.valueOf(str.split("\\s+")[2]);
}

private static String getAcctNum(String str) {
    return str.split("\\s+")[0];
}

private static String getPassword(String str) {
    return str.split("\\s+")[1];
}

private static String[] accts = { "44567-5 mypassword 520.36",
        "1234567-6 anotherpassword 48.20", "4321-0 betterpassword 96.74" };
```

Finally, you can use a [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) to iterate the `accts` and return the balance if you find a match like,

```
public static Double checkID(String acctNum, String pwd) {
    for (String account : accts) {
        if (acctNum.equals(getAcctNum(account))) {
            if (pwd.equals(getPassword(account))) {
                return getBalance(account);
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I haven't learned arrays, also the acct strings I can't change since it was coded by my professor that way.  I'll add that to the description.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace

```
pwd.equals(c.substring(c.indexOf(" "), c.lastIndexOf(" " +1))))
```

with `pwd.equals(c.substring(c.indexOf(" "), c.lastIndexOf(" ") +1)))`

also for a and b

Comment: Thank you! This helped fix the error!  I didn't realize I had put the +1 apart of the string.

Comment: I tried to up vote it but it requires rep 15 to do so

Answer (score 0):

```
if(acctNum.equals(a.split(" ")[0]) && pwd.equals(a.split(" ")[1]))
    {
        result=a.split(" ")[2];
    }
    else if (acctNum.equals(b.split(" ")[0]) && pwd.equals(b.split(" ")[1]))
    {
        result=a.split(" ")[2];
    }
    else if (acctNum.equals(c.split(" ")[0]) && pwd.equals(c.split(" ")[1]))
    {
        result=a.split(" ")[2];
    }
return result;
```

This will get rid of any `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

The next error you get is `java.lang.NullPointerException`, this is because you need to instantiate your scanner. Put this in menu(): `kbd = new Scanner(System.in);` (before `input=kbd.nextInt();`)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to increase attemts in your loop otherwise it just goes on;

```
while(verifyID.equals("error") && attempts<=3) 
        //checkID returns "error" and the attempts are less than or equal to 3.
    {
        attemts++;
        if (attempts==4) //If Maximum attempts reached display message, then exit. 
        {
            System.out.print("Maxium attemps reached.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
```

and in checkID you have make your substrings the right way

```
if(acctNum.equals(a.substring(0, a.indexOf(" "))) 
            && pwd.equals(a.substring(a.indexOf(" ")+1, a.lastIndexOf(" "))))
    {
        result=a.substring(a.lastIndexOf(" ")+1);
    }
```

and use System.out.format in ex. displaybalance

```
System.out.format("Your current balance is : %5.2f\n",acctBal);
```